# Python: Inconsistency in itemgetter()

Tags: python, list, items

I had a strange bug in my code and traced it back to the following behavior of `itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> index_list_1 = [0]
>>> index_list_2 = [0, 1]
>>> list(itemgetter(*index_list_1)(l))
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(itemgetter(*index_list_2)(l))
['abc', 'def']
```

The output I wanted with `index_list_1` would be `['abc']`, but if `itemgetter` only has one item to extract, it returns the element instead of a one-tuple.

Am I using `itemgetter` in the wrong way?

How can I make sure that I get a singleton list if just extracting one value?

Comment: `itemgetter` is designed to do the most convenient thing for any particular initialization parameters, not to do the most convenient thing for varargs. Returning the element directly is the most convenient thing for a single index. (Also, this behavior interacts better with Python's assignment syntax, where `x, y = ...` needs something to unpack and `x = ...` doesn't.)

Comment: Just to be sure: You really need to use `itemgetter` for some reason, right? Otherwise `l[0:1]` and `l[0:2]` would be an obvious solution. The argument of `l` can also be built by a `slice` object: `s = slice(0,2); l[s]` gives you `['abc', 'def']`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good: `itemgetter(*[0])(['abc'])` returns `abc` and you're building a `list` from that. `list('abc')` converts its input to a `list` and returns `['a', 'b' 'c']` .

Comment: It returns a tuple if 2+ indeces are passed but not if 1 index is passed. It throws an error if 0 indeces are passed. It should always return a tuple.

Answer (score -1):

One stupid way to solve the problem is:

```
list(itemgetter(*l+[l[-1]])(m))[:-1]
```

... or

```
list(itemgetter(*l)(m)) if len(l) > 1 else [m[l[0]]]
```

where `l` is the list of indeces to extract the values for an `m` is the list of values.

This does not work if `l` is the empty list but `itemgetter` cannot deal with this case either although the consistent behavior would be to return `()`.

The behavior of `itemgetter` is very unfortunate.

The best option in this case might be to do

```
[m[i] for i in l]
```